# How to make custom login button work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I am trying to have a custom login button function has a button, but when I try, I have another button overlapping the desired login button. Here is what it looks like.

[image]

Here is the HTML.

```
<div class="login_btn">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</div>
```

The button that says submit actually works, so the functionality is not the problem. I just was the button that says Login to work and make the Submit button disappear.

How do I make that happen? I do not know HTML so if more code is needed, please ask and I will supply it.

EDIT: The code

```
<input class="login_btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
```

creates this

[image]

Here is my CSS

```
.container .login_component .login_wrap .login_wp .login_btn {
    height: 55px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background:
        url("http://xiilab.mynetgear.com:81/c.hwang/rems/images/login/login_btn.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not styling the button to look like that? No need to style another element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply your class to the input button.

```
<input class="login_btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
```

Comment: That's correct - the form element uses 'name' to be identified as variables for processing inputs.  Hence, if you points it to name, then the magic does its own work.

Comment: Sorry, that just created a new problem. I will edit the post to show you what that code does.

Comment: Please, just give me the class: `login_btn`

Comment: Ah sorry, it's there now

Answer (score 0):

Try using class with the input

```
<input type="submit" value="" name="commit" id="login_submit" class="login_button"/>
```

CSS:

```
.login_button{background:url(http://xiilab.mynetgear.com:81/c.hwang/rems/images/login/login_btn.png) no-repeat; width:298px; height:52px;
```